# node.js gives me no response

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
FruitsProject % node app.js
```

I run this line on Hyper terminal. And it gives me no response.
Not even an error message did I see.

my app.js code is the following.

```
const {
  MongoClient
} = require('mongodb');
// or as an es module:
// import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb'

// Connection URL
const url = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017';
const client = new MongoClient(url);

// Database Name
const dbName = 'fruitsDB';

async function main() {
    // Use connect method to connect to the server
    await client.connect();
    console.log('Connected successfully to server');
    const db = client.db(dbName);
    const collection = db.collection('fruits');

    // the following code examples can be pasted here...
    collection.insertMany([{
          name: "Apple",
          score: 8,
          review: "Great fruit"
        },
        {
          name: "Orange",
          score: 6,
          review: "Kinda sour"
        }
      ])

      return 'done.';
    }

    main()
      .then(console.log)
      .catch(console.error)
      .finally(() => client.close());
```

I want to run a mongodb server locally and insert data. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

The code at the top of your sample is trying to establish a connection with the Mongo server. You currently cannot add any data using that connection url since there is no Mongo service running locally.

```
// Connection URL
const url = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017';
const client = new MongoClient(url);
```

If you're wanting to run a Mongo server locally, I'd recommend using Docker. In simple terms, Docker is a way of running multiple services on a machine using containers. A container is a running image, which is a stand alone version of a service or application, such as MongoDB. Check out Mongo's image on Docker Hub at https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo.

Answer (score 0):

Your logging is a bit off, here it is corrected and with request execution time measurement:

```js
const {
  MongoClient
} = require('mongodb');
// or as an es module:
// import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb'

// Connection URL
const url = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017';
const client = new MongoClient(url);

// Database Name
const dbName = 'fruitsDB';

async function main() {
  // Use connect method to connect to the server
  await client.connect();
  console.log('Connected successfully to server');
  const db = client.db(dbName);
  const collection = db.collection('fruits');

  // the following code examples can be pasted here...
  collection.insertMany([
    {
      name: "Apple",
      score: 8,
      review: "Great fruit"
    },
    {
      name: "Orange",
      score: 6,
      review: "Kinda sour"
    }
  ])

  return 'done.';
}

const start = new Date(Date.now()).toTimeString();

main()
  .then(() => console.log("Update executed successfully"))
  .catch((e) => console.error(e))
  .finally(() => {
    client.close();
    console.log(`start:\t${start}`);
    console.log(`end:\t${new Date(Date.now()).toTimeString()}`);
  });
```

If you dont have a local MongoDB instance running, you will likely get the below error **after 30s timeout**:

```
MongoServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
```

You should either install [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/community) locally or use the official [Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo) to spin up a local instance, choose according to your needs.